# calling oracle procedure from java by passing sql statement which is taken from as user input

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call a oracle procedure using java.
I'm reading sql query from user and passing to procedure.
so when I'm trying to pass `select * from emp where emp_id like 'XX'` as a statement,
The procedure ends up with the following error:-

```
Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 1, column 103:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "XX" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol ", was inserted before "XX" to continue.
```

How can I overcome this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code for your procedure, and how you call it from Java. (Also suggest you read up on SQL injection, if you aren't already dealing with that possibility.)

Comment: Can you debug code that you cannot see?  Well, neither can we.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `like` is used it is for a character pattern, and not for a fixed value as you indicate `XX`

You should use:

```
select * from emp where emp_id='XX'
```

It may also be because your Java code parses the `'` by `"` character. Check it out.